# Not sure how to use these unnamed structs that were given as prototypes. C

Tags: c, struct

EDIT: These structure definitions were given to me and cannot be altered in any way.

Let's say in `struct DB` I would like to access the name of 3rd element in db. How would I go about that? I would think I would be able to do this:

```
DB->db[2].name;
```

but that doesn't work.

Also, how would I define one of these structs as a parameter inside a function?

```
typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
    unsigned long pass;
} DBEntry;

typedef struct {
    DBEntry db[MAX_ENTRIES];
    int size;
} DB;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Is `DB` a pointer? If not, you don't want the `->` operator, you want `.`. (It might be helpful to show more code. Like the context of the part that "doesn't work".)

Comment: Could you please post the code that 'doesn't work'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no `struct DB`; there is a type name `DB` which identifies an untagged structure type, but that's separate from `struct DB`.

How you access the elements depends on the variable declaration:

```
DB  db1 = ...;
DB *db2 = ...;
```

With variable `db1`, you access the name of the 3rd element using:

```
printf("%s\n", db1.db[2].name);
```

With variable `db2`, you access the name of the 3rd element using:

```
printf("%s\n", db2->db[2].name);
```

You can define a function that takes these types using:

```
void magic_function(DB db1, DB *db2, DBEntry de1, DBEntry *de2)
{
    printf("%s\n", db1.db[0].name);
    printf("%s\n", db2->db[0].name);
    printf("%s\n", de1.name);
    printf("%s\n", de2->name);
}
```

You can declare it in a header using:

```
extern void magic_function(DB db1, DB *db2, DBEntry de1, DBEntry *de2);
```

Personally, I prefer the `extern` there for symmetry with the `extern` declarations for those rare global variables that are declared in the same header, but it is not actually necessary (`extern` is assumed if it is omitted).  If the function is only referenced from a single source file, it should be `static`, of course (and not declared in any header).

Answer (score 3):

First you have to create object for struct `DB`. Then you can access it's members.

```
DB obj;
strcpy(obj.db[2].name, "abc");
```

Answer (score 2):

These are *types*, not *variables*.

To use them:

```
DB db;
db.size = 1;
strcpy(db.db[0].name, "name");
db.db[0].pass = 0xdeadbeef;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare as object like this ..

```
DB db1;
db1.db[0].pass = 35;
```

I think , In your code , you have try to store number of names and access to those elements. If you try that, your `DBEntry` structure should be

```
typedef struct {
    char *name[MAX_NAME + 1];
    unsigned long pass;
} DBEntry;
```